# Does virto commerce support multiple elastic search worker role, and share index data

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, virtocommerce

I have checked the source code, the elasticsearch worker role install the elasticsearch and create the cloud drive from blob "ElasticStorage.vhd", what will happen if i have multiple elasticsearch worker role, then multiple elasticsearch instances will be installed, but i want to know can index data be shared? or each elasticsearch instance hold it's index data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elasticsearch instances form a cluster (you can see in the source, as soon as the instance is started, the list of ip is passed as part of the configuration). So the index data is shared. The cloud drive is used to give some persistence in case instances are crashed. It would be better to setup snapshots instead.

You can also setup elastic search using official plugin instead: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-azure

Comment: thanks, yesterday i already found the elasticsearch cluster, it's very simple to config.